# MS Access Creating Attribute Tagging Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I wanted to ask whether or not MS Access can handle an attribute tagging form. Note, "attribute tagging form" was a term I innovated to describe what I had in mind. If you would happen to know the correct term, please let me know.

My Current Method:
[image: Figure 1]

On left pane, I have the PDF file in question with file preview. On the right, a Microsoft excel file with the title, file name and other attributes.

The task:
[image: Figure 2]
In the left, same PDF. On the right, I need to scroll to the right some distance to mark "Peanuts" and "Soybeans" with "1". Flagging the PDF pertinent to peanuts and soybeans.

The Question:
What I would like to do is create a form in access that would allow me to type out one of the attributes instead of having to scroll back and forth and marking it with a 1. The risk for an error would be too great once there are several dozens attributes to flag.

What I had in mind would be much like stackoverflow's tag function:
[image: Figure 3]
Where I can start typing an attribute, and if there is already one existing, it will autocomplete and I can move onto the next one. This will then reflect onto a database (or spreadsheet) with a 1 in the correct column and row.

Side note: 
I've done some research on my own into Access' tagging function, but it would appear that it would not work to what I have in mind.

```
[Resource 1][4]
[Resource 2][5]
[Resource 3][6]
[Resource 4][7]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is **"search as you type"**. You'll find examples here on SO and elsewhere.

Basically, a text box or combobox has a `On Dirty` event procedure that narrows down a result list as you type the first (or any matching) letters.

In your case, once you've selected a tag, you'd add it to a list, clear the text box, so you can continue with the next tag.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know of that. I'll look into it some more.